# Upgrading Grails 3.1.9 to 3.3.0.M1 BeanCreationException

Tags: grails, upgrade

Hey I'm trying to upgrade our Grails application from 3.1.9 to the current release 3.3.0.M1, but I'm running into some errors I can't figure out. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction... I can provide more information if need be. Thanks!

Here's the stacktrace (I had to cut out most of it due to size limitations. [Link to pastebin](https://pastebin.com/j2YWnyVX)):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsInterceptorMappedInterceptor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#42ced544' of type [org.grails.plugins.web.interceptors.GrailsInterceptorHandlerInterceptorAdapter] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#42ced544': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'navigationalUtilCurrentLinkIdInterceptor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'navigationUtil': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTagLibraryLookup' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gspTagLibraryLookup': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grails.plugin.formfields.FormFieldsTagLib': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanPropertyAccessorFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.grails.beans.ConstraintsEvaluator' while setting bean property 'constraintsEvaluator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.beans.ConstraintsEvaluator': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'constraintsEvaluatorClass' of bean class [org.grails.validation.DefaultConstraintEvaluator]: Bean property 'constraintsEvaluatorClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at myApp.Application.main(Application.groovy:12)
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Also, dependent on how you are implementing the upgrade can you share any command line code?

Comment: Using Windows 7. Can you clarify about command line code? Output for grails -v is : `Grails Version: 3.3.0. Groovy Version: 2.4.10 JVM Version: 1.7.0_80`. My Gradle.properties is : `grailsVersion=3.3.0.M1 gormVersion=6.1.3.RELEASE gradleWrapperVersion=3.5`

Comment: @William I also followed the instructions from here: https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html#upgrading31x

Comment: I meant the commands you used to actually begin the upgrade or configure any properties. I'm trying to retrace your steps in the implementation of the upgrade.

I've been referencing those some docs as well, but your specific problem seems to be a collection of problems which cascade down from a base configuration issue, at least that's what it looks like. So I wanted to see if we could narrow it down to a specific part of the upgrade which might have produced the error.

Comment: @William Ok that makes sense. Steps I took: downloaded the zip containing grails 3.3 (tested with create-app). Cloned my app into a new directory. Cleaned up my build.gradle dependencies. I also changed my gradle.properties to above This app is also setup as a mutli-grails-app project, so I did the same thing on the other Grails app. I then did gradlew.bat clean, gradlew.bat build. and grails run-app -Dgrails.env=local. The only code I had to change for it to build was to change the following imports: `import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean`

Comment: @William I changed those imports to :`import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean`